# Simple Regression: Which parameter follows the t-distribution

Tags: regression, t-test, t-distribution

In simple linear regression for the problem Y=aX+b; the "goodness" of the coefficient a can be estimated through a hypothesis test which computes the statistic, $t=\frac{a'-0}{SE(a')}$.

Which of the following follows a t distribution:

1- Is it t?

2- Is it a?

3- Is it both?

If one computed some other measure such as $t_2=\frac{2a'-0}{8SE(a')}$, would it also follow a t-distribution as long as it is computed on a sample? why/why not?

Comment: Why are you subtracting $0$?

Comment: @Henry The default test for almost all software is a comparison of each coefficient to zero.  (It may be misleading, though, to characterize that as an estimate of the "goodness" of the coefficient, whatever that might even mean.)